# App Store developer bank account requirements

Tags: ios-appstore

Does anyone know if I'm signing up for a developer account (connected to company), does the designated bank account for need to be in same country/currency as the company, or can it be in another country?

For example, company registered in Estonia but with bank account in the UK.

Thanks.

Comment: Even if Apple allows this, why would you deal with the regulatory differences across two countries? Just incorporate where you want to bank. Maybe there’s a good backstory about your situation so  I won’t downvote this -  it’s perfectly clear and even if there’s a yes/no answer pair. A general answer might also help a larger group of people using this Apple service.

Comment: @bmike - It's a company structuring matter, particularly relevant to web businesses and location-independent businesses.